# crystalreports subreports

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

In crystal reports, when i place mouse over the sub-report, it shows as a link and if i click on it, it comes as a new report. How can i prevent it ?

Answer (score 2):

Set the EnableDrillDown property of CrystalReportViewer false. This should solve the issue. You can see this link as well: http://weblogs.sdn.sap.com/cs/blank/view/wlg/22781